# User updated- audit logs

Tags: logging, audit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbJDR.png)in the audit logs, what is ***user  updated referring to***?, i have a case where the customer only use 1 LSP and there is activity in projects according to the audi logs from an old lsp who they know longer use. That user is also not on the dashboard, they havent been added

Comment: i cannot add multiple images but i have another screengrab from showing the users email address.